# How do I get/address elements from an object inside an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have an object called "message"

"message" holds an anonymous object (as a string):

```
{"action":"wakeup","hello":"testing123"}
// this is what I get when I output "message" with alert()
```

How do I address/get the content of "hello" from that?

Comment: Are you sure it's an object and not a string? `alert()` doesn't show object contents.

Comment: It IS actually a string converted from an object with JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `message` is a string (check it using `typeof message === 'string'`), you can create an object from it using `message = JSON.parse(message)`. After that you'll have `message.action` (value 'wakeup') and `message.hello` (value 'testing123') available in `message`, now being an Object.

If `message` already is an Object, `message.wakeup` and `message.hello` should both be available without conversion.

Comment: Spot on. I just got it working a second before you wrote this ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a JSON object so you should use the eval function to convert it to json and you can use it as a property of variable that will contain the result of convertion

Answer (score 0):

Since your using JSON and jQuery I'll assume that you're getting the data from an AJAX call. You could use the `$.getJSON()` method which will give a nice fully formed Javascript object.

If that's not correct you should be calling `eval()` on the message string to create a Javascript object.